# How to prevent restarting one of the actvities in Android Tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-orientation

In my app, I have one tab host and 3 activities A, B, C as tab contents.When orientation changes, current activity is restarting. Activity B, has a web view, to which i am loading some video links dynamically. When user clicks on these videos, they are getting played. when orientation changes, B is getting restart, which makes my web view clear also unable to resume the video from stopped position. For this I want to prevent Only Activity B getting restart (this is just one case, but I have many other valid reasons for not killing activity B).

What I want is how to prevent only "B" getting destroy and recreate. I tried overriding `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`
both in tabhost activity and Activty "B". But it is calling Activity B's onCreate method along with onConfigurationChanged. calling onCreate in B, makes my view refresh and lost state of B activity. So, **in short, is there any way to prevent destroy/create(2nd time) getting called for one of the activities in android tab host.** Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to restrict the orientation changes else activity will be restarted on once orientation changed.

To restrict the orientation changes you need to add this line in your manifest file for all the activity you are using or else you can add it in to application itself.

```
<activity android:name="A"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity> 
<activity android:name="B"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity> 
<activity android:name="C"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: Even then also B's onCreate method is getting called. Read my question clearly.

Comment: above line can restrict your activity to restart on configuration change you can add this line for any one of your activity ... . remaining you can do with your own logics . what else you are looking for ?

Comment: I mistakenly devoted u r answer, I thought it as un accept. If you give  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" to Activity "B", it won't work. Why because along with tabhost activity all children will destroy. If you give same to both tab host activity and B also it does n't work.